# Remove query strings from static resources

Tags: asp.net, scriptresource.axd, pingdom

My website is running on ASP.NET platform and recently i test my website on pingdom and i found the below error.

> Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching
>   servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the
>   URL for the following resources:
>   https://projectsdeal.co.uk/ScriptResource.axd?d ...
>   63Nawdr4rAt1lvT7c_zyBEkV9INg0&t=ffffffffe3663df5
>   https://projectsdeal.co.uk/ScriptResource.axd?d ...
>   JGTlZFM0WRegQM9wdaZV3fQWMKwg2&t=ffffffffe3663df5

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple leave it as it is (its not an error !) - **you can not remove this query string from resource because this is the id** on how to load that resource from asp.net

The message that you get is actually talk for a proxy caching servers - what is a proxy caching server ? a middle computer that cache pages of your site, not the actually client computer - that can hold in cache that page and not bring slower your site in general.

**So your client can hold that resource on cache** if you set them correctly, and from what I see asp.net take care correctly and you resource are cached just fine - see this screen shot.

[image]

Now if you wish to add even more aggressive cache you can use the global.asax and do something like

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    if (cTheFile.EndsWith("WebResource.axd", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        JustSetSomeCache(app);
    }
}

private static void JustSetSomeCache(HttpApplication app)
{
    app.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("post-check=900, pre-check=3600");
    app.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(32));
    app.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(32, 0, 0));
    app.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    app.Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
}
```

What is the different ? The second cache is not check the server at all for file change as the asp.net do, you can gain one webserver call.

Comment: can you please tell me how to set resource on cache correctly

Comment: then how can i solve this Remove query strings from static resources because it decreases my profile score on pindom test

Comment: @NomalAfzal I think that is too much to look at them, the program that gives you that results don't know everything, is just a suggestion. You have other issue to take care (like the viewstate, you need to compress is at least), this is not one that I personally look it.

Comment: @NomalAfzal Look at that analysis https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojectsdeal.co.uk%2F   your score is 89/100 that is very good consider that you have some other issues that can not see